# What is the time complexity of LR parsers?

Tags: compilers, parsers

Bottom up parsers in worst case take O($n^3$) time, and i believe that LR parser being a bottom up parser should also take O($n^3$) time, but i read on wiki that they are able to solve problems in linear time. How can this be possible?

Comment: Which "wiki" did you read that? Could you provide a reference or quoted text?

Comment: @dkaeae https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser   , Moreover see the ans below provided by rici, so he is also suggesting O(n)!

Comment: @downvoter please explain the proper reason of downvote rather than downvoting without any justification..PEACE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they can only recognise a subset of context-free languages. In fact, it is the subset which can be parsed in linear time: languages with a deterministic grammar.

Comment: so worst case case of LR parser is O(n)?

Comment: @hirak: yes, the LR parser always takes O(n) time. It can only take less time if the input can be rejected early.